# SQL Trigger; conditional sum in table a to cause update in table b

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, conditional-statements

I have three tables. One for customers, one for orders and one for order items.
I am trying to create a trigger which will do the following:
after an insert into the order items table, sum the group wise total order quantity by customer id.
If the value is greater than some value, say 5 for test purposes, then update the customer table by flagging the customer with a discount.

This is required to be accomplished in one trigger only.

Here are the tables.
Customer:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1001, 'MORALES', 'BONITA', 'P.O. BOX 651', 'EASTPOINT', 'FL', '32328', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1002, 'THOMPSON', 'RYAN', 'P.O. BOX 9835', 'SANTA MONICA', 'CA', '90404', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1003, 'SMITH', 'LEILA', 'P.O. BOX 66', 'TALLAHASSEE', 'FL', '32306', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1004, 'PIERSON', 'THOMAS', '69821 SOUTH AVENUE', 'BOISE', 'ID', '83707', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1005, 'GIRARD', 'CINDY', 'P.O. BOX 851', 'SEATTLE', 'WA', '98115', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1006, 'CRUZ', 'MESHIA', '82 DIRT ROAD', 'ALBANY', 'NY', '12211', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1007, 'GIANA', 'TAMMY', '9153 MAIN STREET', 'AUSTIN', 'TX', '78710', 1003);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1008, 'JONES', 'KENNETH', 'P.O. BOX 137', 'CHEYENNE', 'WY', '82003', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1009, 'PEREZ', 'JORGE', 'P.O. BOX 8564', 'BURBANK', 'CA', '91510', 1003);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1010, 'LUCAS', 'JAKE', '114 EAST SAVANNAH', 'ATLANTA', 'GA', '30314', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1011, 'MCGOVERN', 'REESE', 'P.O. BOX 18', 'CHICAGO', 'IL', '60606', NULL); 
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1012, 'MCKENZIE', 'WILLIAM', 'P.O. BOX 971', 'BOSTON', 'MA', '02110', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1013, 'NGUYEN', 'NICHOLAS', '357 WHITE EAGLE AVE.', 'CLERMONT', 'FL', '34711', 1006);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1014, 'LEE', 'JASMINE', 'P.O. BOX 2947', 'CODY', 'WY', '82414', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1015, 'SCHELL', 'STEVE', 'P.O. BOX 677', 'MIAMI', 'FL', '33111', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1016, 'DAUM', 'MICHELL', '9851231 LONG ROAD', 'BURBANK', 'CA', '91508', 1010);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1017, 'NELSON', 'BECCA', 'P.O. BOX 563', 'KALMAZOO', 'MI', '49006', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1018, 'MONTIASA', 'GREG', '1008 GRAND AVENUE', 'MACON', 'GA', '31206', NULL);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1019, 'SMITH', 'JENNIFER', 'P.O. BOX 1151', 'MORRISTOWN', 'NJ', '07962', 1003);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES (1020, 'FALAH', 'KENNETH', 'P.O. BOX 335', 'TRENTON', 'NJ', '08607', NULL);
```

Bookorders:

```
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1000,1005,'31-MAR-23','02-APR-23','1201 ORANGE AVE', 'SEATTLE', 'WA', '98114');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1001,1010,'31-MAR-23','01-APR-23', '114 EAST SAVANNAH', 'ATLANTA', 'GA', '30314');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1002,1011,'31-MAR-23','01-APR-23','58 TILA CIRCLE', 'CHICAGO', 'IL', '60605');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1003,1001,'01-APR-23','01-APR-23','958 MAGNOLIA LANE', 'EASTPOINT', 'FL', '32328');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1004,1020,'01-APR-23','05-APR-23','561 ROUNDABOUT WAY', 'TRENTON', 'NJ', '08601');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1005,1018,'01-APR-23','02-APR-23', '1008 GRAND AVENUE', 'MACON', 'GA', '31206');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1006,1003,'01-APR-23','02-APR-23','558A CAPITOL HWY.', 'TALLAHASSEE', 'FL', '32307');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1007,1007,'02-APR-23','04-APR-23', '9153 MAIN STREET', 'AUSTIN', 'TX', '78710');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1008,1004,'02-APR-23','03-APR-23', '69821 SOUTH AVENUE', 'BOISE', 'ID', '83707');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1009,1005,'03-APR-23','05-APR-23','9 LIGHTENING RD.', 'SEATTLE', 'WA', '98110');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1010,1019,'03-APR-23','04-APR-23','384 WRONG WAY HOME', 'MORRISTOWN', 'NJ', '07960');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1011,1010,'03-APR-23','05-APR-23', '102 WEST LAFAYETTE', 'ATLANTA', 'GA', '30311');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1012,1017,'03-APR-23',NULL,'1295 WINDY AVENUE', 'KALMAZOO', 'MI', '49002');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1013,1014,'03-APR-23','04-APR-23','7618 MOUNTAIN RD.', 'CODY', 'WY', '82414');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1014,1007,'04-APR-23','05-APR-23', '9153 MAIN STREET', 'AUSTIN', 'TX', '78710');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1015,1020,'04-APR-23',NULL,'557 GLITTER ST.', 'TRENTON', 'NJ', '08606');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1016,1003,'04-APR-23',NULL,'9901 SEMINOLE WAY', 'TALLAHASSEE', 'FL', '32307');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1017,1015,'04-APR-23','05-APR-23','887 HOT ASPHALT ST', 'MIAMI', 'FL', '33112');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1018,1001,'05-APR-23',NULL,'95812 HIGHWAY 98', 'EASTPOINT', 'FL', '32328');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1019,1018,'05-APR-23',NULL, '1008 GRAND AVENUE', 'MACON', 'GA', '31206');
INSERT INTO BOOKORDER
VALUES (1020,1008,'05-APR-23',NULL,'195 JAMISON LANE', 'CHEYENNE', 'WY', '82003');
```

Bookorderitems

```
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1000,1,'3437212490',1); 
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1001,1,'9247381001',1); 
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1001,2,'2491748320',1); 
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1002,1,'8843172113',2); 
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1003,1,'8843172113',1); 
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1003,2,'1059831198',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1003,3,'3437212490',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1004,1,'2491748320',2);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1005,1,'2147428890',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1006,1,'9959789321',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1007,1,'3957136468',3);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1007,2,'9959789321',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1007,3,'8117949391',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1007,4,'8843172113',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1008,1,'3437212490',2);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1009,1,'3437212490',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1009,2,'0401140733',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1010,1,'8843172113',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1011,1,'2491748320',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1012,1,'8117949391',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1012,2,'1915762492',2);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1012,3,'2491748320',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1012,4,'0401140733',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1013,1,'8843172113',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1014,1,'0401140733',2);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1015,1,'3437212490',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1016,1,'2491748320',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1017,1,'8117949391',2);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1018,1,'3437212490',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1018,2,'8843172113',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1019,1,'0401140733',1);
INSERT INTO BOOKORDERITEM
VALUES (1020,1,'3437212490',1);
```

First I have added the discount column to customer

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER
ADD CUST_DISCOUNT number(1)
Default 0
;
```

I have gotten the select statement sorted.

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER.CUST_lName, 
    SUM(BOOKORDERITEM.boi_qty)
FROM BOOKORDERITEM
JOIN BOOKORDER ON BOOKORDER.bo_ordernum = BOOKORDERITEM.bo_ordernum
JOIN CUSTOMER ON BOOKORDER.cust_num = CUSTOMER.cust_num
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUST_lname, CUSTOMER.cust_num;
```

My trigger is so far:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER customer_discount
AFTER INSERT ON BOOKORDERITEM

FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
    s NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CUSTOMER.CUST_lName, 
        SUM(BOOKORDERITEM.boi_qty) INTO s
    FROM BOOKORDERITEM
    JOIN BOOKORDER ON BOOKORDER.bo_ordernum = BOOKORDERITEM.bo_ordernum
    JOIN CUSTOMER ON BOOKORDER.cust_num = CUSTOMER.cust_num
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUST_lname, CUSTOMER.cust_num;
    
    IF s > 5  THEN 
        SET CUSTOMER.cust_discount = 1;
    END IF;
        
END;    
/
```

And it compiles with errors:

Trigger CUSTOMER_DISCOUNT compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

14/9      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
14/13     PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Errors: check compiler log

The outcome I am after is the row in the customer table for cust_num = 1007 to have cust_discount = 1.

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be very greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You are selecting two columns and there is just one into variable (into s). There is also SET without UPDATE table command... You can't do that...

Comment: This is a much more challenging problem that it first appears.  Lets say your trigger code compiles fine - you're still got a problem because you can't see uncommitted changes from other sessions, which means you can miss counts and therefore incorrectly set your flag.  See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=restricting-number-of-entries for options and considerations